# add links discord presenceRPC

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in `C#` and I am trying to add url buttons to be able to add a web url but I don't know how to add it, this is my code:

```
this.handlers = default(DiscordRpc.EventHandlers);
DiscordRpc.Initialize("xxx", ref this.handlers, true, null);
this.handlers = default(DiscordRpc.EventHandlers);
DiscordRpc.Initialize("xxx", ref this.handlers, true, null);
this.presence.details = "Barcelona";
this.presence.state = "Barcelona";
this.presence.startTimestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
this.presence.largeImageKey = "https://media.tenor.com/Y_bfmgZ2sZ0AAAAM/aubameyang-fc-barcelona.gif";
this.presence.smallImageKey = "https://media.tenor.com/Y_bfmgZ2sZ0AAAAM/aubameyang-fc-barcelona.gif";
this.presence.largeImageText = "HI";

this.presence.smallImageText = "FCB";
DiscordRpc.UpdatePresence(ref this.presence);
```

This is what I am trying to add.
[image]

Comment: You should provide more detailed infos like, what UI framework are you using? winforms? wpf? blazor?...etc.

Comment: .net framework? .net core?

Comment: using .net framework

Comment: Is you question about how to add a button on form in .net framework?

Comment: That's what I want to do, add button links but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You can add a button visually by dragging it from the toolbox on your form or programmatically like: 

this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
this.Controls.Add(this.button1);

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Button` class and add it to the forms `Controls` collection as shown below

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.twitterButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

    // 
    // twitterButton
    // 
    this.twitterButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, 111);
    this.twitterButton.Name = "twitterButton";
    this.twitterButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(89, 23);
    this.twitterButton.TabIndex = 1;
    this.twitterButton.Text = "twitter";
    this.twitterButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.twitterButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.twitterButton_Click);

    this.Controls.Add(this.twitterButton);
}
```